# What is the best approach for a set of data that is irregular and uneven

Tags: regression, panel-data, vector-autoregression, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have a dataset with 975 observations from 112 different categories. The timespan of this dataset is 18 years. However, the data is unevenly spaced and even acquired:

While some categories have only 1 observation for these 18 years, some others have 25, almost2 per year. This makes trying to set the periodicity of the data quite complicated, if not downright impossible.

What type of regression would be best suited for this? It does not quite fit an unbalanced panel, because the periodicity is uneven, and also does not quite seems to fit with Vector Auto Regressive, again, as the series are highly irregular amongst them.

Comment: 25 observations over 18 years is closer to 1 per year than it is to 2 per year - it's below 1.4. There are methods for dealing with data at irregular time points, though having so many categories and some being so rare suggests you'll need some strong assumptions and external knowledge about things like period. What are you trying to find out from the data? (What's the aim here?)

Comment: These are credit ratings, I'd like to know the correlation between a particular rating in consecutive periods.

Comment: continuous-time equivalents of AR(1)-type processes (which can be used for irregular series) might let you calculate such a correlation, if you have enough data to do it.

Comment: Perfect, @Glen_b, I shall use that approach.